# Symfony form differences between row and widget

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

What is the differences between `form_widget` and `form_row`?

I know that in `form_row` i can add label in attributes, and `form_widget` render all fields.

are there others difference?

Comment: the best is to read the doc when learning : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

**form_widget**

> Renders the HTML widget of a given field. If you apply this to an
>   entire form or collection of fields, each underlying form row will be
>   rendered.

**form_row**

> Renders the "row" of a given field, which is the combination of the
>   field's label, errors and widget.

So main difference is that **form_widget** will render also child fields (if they exists).

Comment: I think the form_row contains the form_widget as well as errors and labels.