# Symfony twig div

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I made a form with the FormBuilder of Symfony.
When I put my form in twig, the `form_start(form`) and `form_end(form)`, it add a tag  for each input.

I don't understand why twig adds a  tag.
What is the solution to remove this  tag

Thanks for your answer :)
Also, my formbuilder is like that :

```
->add('title', TextType::class, array(
      'label'=>false,
      'attr'=>array('autofocus'=>true)
      ))
```

my twig is like that :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 p-1">
        {{ form_row(form_record.title, {'attr':{'class':"form-control", 'placeholder':"Description"|trans, 'title':"Description"|trans }}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form_record.title) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 pt-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

and the result in the html source code is :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 p-1">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="app__title" name="app_[title]" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" title="Description">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So Twig add the

```
<div>
```

that I don't want. How can I remove this autocompleted tag?
I tried the

```
{% do form_record.title.set rendered %}
```

but maybe I think that it does not work.

Comment: what symfony version are you using? it's been a while since I've worked with symfony but, there is way you can override the default way templates are rendered, from the entire form to very specific items, in this case you want to find the function that renders `form_row` and remove the `div` tags in there. of course this approach will cause ALL form rows in your app to be rendered without said `div` tags

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Okay it seems I misunderstood the issue at first.
I thought you wanted to hide a field you had in your form which can be done with

```
{% do form.myField.setRendered %}
```

Now that I understand the issue, I believe it comes from the way your field is being printed.

There are 3 main components to a form field.

```
Label: form_label(form.field)
Widget: form_widget(form.field)
Errors: form_errors(form.field)
```

There is a way to print all three components at once. The function is

```
form_row(form.field)
```

Here comes the culprit: form_row(). Because it normally prints 3 different components, it adds a div around it!

Futhermore, by looking at the form type and seing `'label' => false`, I can say that the label was printing at first using form_row.

To avoid having to define `'label'=>false` everytime, you can simply print your form field in this manner:

```
{{ form_widget(form_record.title, {'attr':{'class':"form-control", 'placeholder':"Description"|trans, 'title':"Description"|trans }}) }}
{{ form_errors(form_record.title) }}
```

You can simply omit `{{form_label(form_record.title)}}` and it won't print.

On the other hand, I also noticed something that might be okay but seem wrong with the given example.

In the twig you shared, the form starts with `{{ form_start(form) }}` but then the field is `{{ form_row(form_record.title)}}`.

From where I come from `form_record` is undefined here. I would use `{{ form_row(form.title)}}`

Anyways, the explanation for the difference between form_row and form_widget can be found here: [Symfony form differences between row and widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199364/symfony-form-differences-between-row-and-widget)

Enjoy!